# SoftLayer REST API to delete a user profile

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am attempting to delete a user profile like this:

```
curl -X DELETE -k -n "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/406673.json"

{"error":"Function (\"deleteObject\") is not a valid method for this service.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

How do I remove/delete a user profile? Sure hope the search of the API reference is returned.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a user, try the following REST request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[user_id]/editObject
```

Method: POST
Json Payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "userStatusId": 1021
    }
  ]
}
```

The statuses for the user can be:

```
1001 = Active;
1002 = Disabled; 
1003 = Inactive; 
1021 = cancel_pending;
1022 = VPN Only
```

References:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/editObject